# Lojasiewicz's structure theorem

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analytic-structures

The Lojasiewicz structure theorem on p. 169 in the book of Krantz/Parks **A primer of real analytic functions** confuses me. According to the stratification property, the zeroes of a real analytic function can not be isolated points in e.g. $\mathbb{R}^2$. But what about for example $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ where $(0,0)$ is the only zero?

Comment: It looks like a mistake. The sets in the stratification should get larger in dimensions, but some dimensions might get skipped. They seem to require nonempty sets of each dimension.

Comment: I think the dimensions are right. The lower dimensional sets are contained in the closure of the higer dimensional sets. But indeed maybe they require nonempty sets in each dimension. A second possibility is that the rotation (or more general a suitable transformation) in the beginning of the theorem takes in fact place in the complex space, But is this possible?